# Relative Geolocation if a user denies actual geolocation?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

At some point in the past I went on the Foursquare website and before I allowed permission for the site to geolocate me, the map was already centered on a near-by major city. How was this done? Is there some way to get a vague sense of where the user is even if they deny geolocation? I would like to do something similar to provide relevant data to a user even if they deny geolocation

Comment: location by IP address is one alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For approximate location, look for ip to location solutions.

E.g http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Or you can get an ip to location database and implement it locally. You will need to get updates periodically.

Answer (score 1):

IP ranges tend to stay within a fairly small geographic area. And lots of folks have built databases of these geo-IP areas, some of which you can tap into fairly easily for free.

See http://ipinfodb.com/index.php